# Proving the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ containing $S$ is a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $S$ a subset of $G$. Let $L(S)$ be the intersection of all the subgroups of $G$ that contain $S$. Prove $L(S)$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I have this:

We have that $\mathrm{id}_G\in L(S)$ because all of the groups being intersected have $\mathrm{id}_G$, and similarly we have that $S\subseteq L(S)$. What about inverses?

This is where I got stuck with my logic. Is there a theorem for this?

Comment: The English in your original question did not make much sense. After Ethan's answer, I was able to figure out what you were really trying to ask and fixed your question as best I could.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $x \in H_1$ and $y \in H_2$, where $H_1$ and $H_2$ are subgroups of $G$ containing $S$. Then let $H = H_1H_2$.

Comment: Sorry, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Say $x\in L(S)$. By definition of $L(S)$, if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $S$, then $x\in H$. What can you conclude about $x^{-1}$ with respect to $H$? Since your conclusion should hold for all $H$, then you can make a conclusion about $L(S)$ since it is the intersection of all such $H$. You can do the same for $x,y\in L(S)$ to conclude that $xy\in L(S)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $L(S)=\bigcap\{H: H \leq G, S \subseteq H \}=\langle S \rangle$, the subgroup *generated* by the set $S$.